# How can I increase the font size in Xcode for swift

Tags: xcode

I am brand new to swift and Xcode and about to start a iOS learning module.

Problem: I am struggling to find the setting for font size in the Xcode playground.

Question: How can I increase the font size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

go to the top left of your screen while in xcode.

Go Xcode -> Preferences -> Fonts & Colours. Highlight all the words in the big center box.

The click on the "T" icon (Text) just below.

Select your size and you're sorted!

Comment: @ChrisDormani no problem

Comment: Life saver, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: 2022 update the `Fonts and Colors` section has been renamed `Themes`